# Why is the i++ used in arrays

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int myArray[5];     // array of 5 integers lol
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++ )  // 0 - 4
    {
        std::cout << "Value for myArray[" << i << " ]: ";
        std::cin >> myArray[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
    std::cout << i << ": " << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is i++ required for this program to work?

Comment: In the future you'll find some formatting help in the side bar of the edit screen.

Comment: What's so funny about an array of 5 integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you don't execute `i++` (or any other statement which increments `i`), `i` will remain `0`, the condition `i < 5` will always remain true and the loop will never end.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else for helping me~!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that you liked best. You can do this by clicking the check mark on the left side of the person's post.

Answer (score 3):

The ++ is the increment operator, and increments the value of i in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i++ is just a short hand for

```
i = i + 1;
```

If you don't increment your loop counter then the loop will never end for example this would be an infinite loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i+ 1)
  /*do something*/
```

Answer (score 0):

i++ increases the i variable.. you can also use i-- in the loop to decrease the i variable.

Or even i+=2 to increment the variable by two.