# Is i reserved for use in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've tried and haven't found any documentation on using `i` as a variable, but understand it's short for index or iteration and [how it's used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313669/why-is-the-i-used-in-arrays). When asked to write a basic for loop that prints to the console all the numbers from 10 to 1 in descending order, using `i` works but is using `i` appropriate? Is `i` reserved for use in arrays? Is it bad practice to use `i` outside of working with arrays?

Ideally, this is answered with a style guide reference *(fact > opinion).*

```
for (i = 10; i > 0; i--){console.log(i)}
```

versus

```
for (num = 10; num > 0; num--){console.log(num)}
```

**I am asking about best practices.**
**The code works fine** :)

Comment: You can use whatever variable you like as long as it's valid syntax. `i` isn't reserved for anything and it's just programmer habit to use it that way.

Comment: `num` is actually less informative than `i`, despite having more letters. `i` tells  you that it's probably iterating over positive integers, not just any sort of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is just common; you can, and are encouraged to use more natural/descriptive names.

Compare:

`for (i = 7; i  > 0; i--)`

vs.

`for (day = 7; day > 0; day--)`

even without a single comment you can figure out what the loop is for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as a variable reserved for this kind of thing. `i` happens to be a commonly used convention, but it certainly isn't a reserved word, either in JavaScript or any other language.

Programming best practice is generally to use variable names that are meaningful and for which the purpose can be understood if you come back to it in a year's time. Most lint checkers will throw up a warning if you use short variable names like `i`.

I would say that it's okay to use a short variable name for a loop, as long as the loop is short and the variable short-lived. But for a longer loop, where the loop variable is used more often, I would prefer to have a more meaningful variable name than `i`.

Comment: actually `i` is kind of reserved (for integers) in some old languages ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning for the `i` variable name in JavaScript. The only reason to use it as a loop variable is convension, there is nothing that changes by using that name rather than any other name, and there is no restriction against using it in any other way.

The use of `i` as a loop counter is a convenient fallback, when there is no other logical name to use.

The use of the variable names `i`, `j`, `k` and so on as local counter variables comes originally from FORTRAN, where variables starting with the letters `i` to `n` are integer variables. It has then become a convention in several other languages eventhough the variable naming doesn't affect the type of the variable.

Answer (score -2):

variable `i` is just a popular short for iteration or iterating but is a simple variable, it is not a reserved word, even `count` variable isn't too.
And check if you want to work with cycle `for` I recommend you to use `in` statement, see this example:

```
var myArray = ["aa", "bb"];

// Object() augmented
Object.prototype.newMethod = "cc";
// for-in loop
for (var i in myArray) {
console.log(myArray[i]); //"aa", bb", "cc"
}
```

hope I answered your question, Cheers

Comment: Bad advice (about `for… in` used on arrays), and please don't capitalize things that should or must be lowercase in JavaScript.

Comment: Please don't use `for..in` for arrays.  It won't iterate over what you think it will.

Comment: capitalizing variables is not a problem as you said @Touffi, and I did not capitalize something that should not be capitalized. I understand that JavaScript is lower-case sensitive, but in this example, tell me, what exactly according to you, I did put wrong?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it will iterate over the members of array, it's clear.